# changing culture(language) when button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources, globalization, culture

I have a website using framework 4. I made language change with global resources. on the button click code behind i use these codes.

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dil = "en-US";
    var ci = new CultureInfo(dil); //TO_DO Route culture 
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
    Session["culture"] = ci;

}
```

an also my resx files:

-PB.resx

-PB.en-US.resx

-PB.ru-RU.resx

default language is work fine but how can i change to english and russian? where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it after a long search. this is answer and all codes you need. I make this for the master page in visual studio 2010.

You can use ispostback in page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //only does it on non-postback because otherwise the selected 
    //value will not reach event handler correctly 
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        dil = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
    }


}
```

after then we can add button click and cookies

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    dil = "en-US";
    //var ci = new CultureInfo(dil); //TO_DO Route culture 
    //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
    //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
    //Session["culture"] = ci;

    //Sets the cookie that is to be used by Global.asax
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CultureInfo");
    cookie.Value = dil;
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

    //Set the culture and reload the page for immediate effect. 
    //Future effects are handled by Global.asax
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
                  new CultureInfo(dil);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
                  new CultureInfo(dil);
    Server.Transfer(Request.Path);

}
```

and last global.asax file helps solving this problem.

```
  //*
 Public void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {     
 // Code that runs on application startup                                                            
 HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CultureInfo"];
 if (cookie != null && cookie.Value != null) 
 {
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new  
 System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new     
 System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
 }
 else
 {
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new   
 System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR");
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new   
 System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR");
 }
 }
 //*
```

If you are using html tags instead of .net tags you can use these for adding text control.

```
<a><asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources: PB, Home %>"  /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you should store language data in cookie. To set page language, override the InitializeCulture method.

```
 protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        var currentLanguage= HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["dil"];
        string defaultLanguage="tr";
        if(currentLanguage==null)
        {
        //set cookie to defaultLanguage
        }
        else{
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(currentLanguage.Value);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        }
    }
```

To change language by clicking a button

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dil = "en-US";
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(dil);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    HttpCookie hc = new HttpCookie("dil");
    hc.Expires=DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
    hc.Value=dil;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(hc);
}
```

Comment: how can i set the default language in cookie. I don't know using cookie!

Comment: //set cookie to defaultLanguage    
    HttpCookie hc = new HttpCookie("dil");
    hc.Expires=DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
    hc.Value="tr";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(hc);

Comment: unfortunately my c# doesn't support. I use c# 4th version =(

Comment: and also i want to make this in master page. i can't use InitializeCulture(). it is working in page

Comment: You can use Application_BeginRequest method in Global.asax file instade of InitializeCulture